# Malliavin derivative of stopped Brownian motion

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Cross-posted from: "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917971/malliavin-derivative-of-stopped-brownian-motion"

I have a small question concerning the Malliavin derivatives. It could be rather simple, but I am unsure.

Let $B_t$ stand for the standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Denote
$$T = \inf\{t| \|B_t\| = 1\}.$$
That is, $T$ is the first exit time from the unit ball.

I am interested in calculating the Malliavin derivative $DB_T$.
The immediate suspect is $DB_T = 1_{[0,T]}$.
I could not prove it though and I suspect it is not 100% correct.

Is the functional $B_T$ even Malliavin differentiable? If so, how to obtain the derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Stopped Brownian motion is not Malliavin differentiable because if it was it would imply that $T$ is constant (see footnote pg.4 [Locally Lipschitz BSDE driven by a continuous martingale
path-derivative approach](https://www.monash.edu/__data/assets/pdf_file/0011/1194635/10-PathDiff4.pdf)).

We would have that $W_{T}=\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{s\leq T}dW_{s}\in \mathbb{D}^{1,2}$ and $1_{s\leq T}\in \mathbb{D}^{1,2}$. However, by Nualart's proposition 1.2.6 (in "Malliavin and Related topics") we would get that $P[s\leq T]=0$ or $1$.

However, there is some work in [Hitting times for Gaussian processes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606086.pdf) that still manages to get related estimates for hitting times using Malliavin calculus.