# techniques in studying moments of shifted integral process $\mu(T_{a},T_{a}+t)$

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

We have a strictly increasing measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$ given by $\mu(0,x):=\int_{0}^{x}e^{X(s)-\frac{1}{2}\ln1/\epsilon}ds$, where $X(s)$ is a mean zero Gaussian field with truncated log covariance $R(|t-s|)=E[X(s)X(t)]=\ln(\frac{\delta}{\epsilon \vee |t-s|\wedge \delta})$.

Apparently very little is known about the inverse $T_{a}$ of this measure i.e. $\mu(0,T_{a})=a$. In computing the moments of increments $E[(T_{b}-T_{a})^p]$ for $0<a<b$ we end up with having to understand moments for the shifted $\mu(T_{a},T_{a}+t)$ (analogous to "Slepian process") and thus understanding $e^{X(T_{a}+s)}$ (even the expectation $E[e^{X(T_{a}+s)}]$ is hard to understand).

I list here some references and ideas in estimating $E[\mu(T_{a},T_{a}+t)^{q}]$.

- If X is further an Ito process, then one can use a change of variables to study $e^{X_{T_a}}$ (["First Hitting Time of Integral Diffusions and Applications"](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2923782))
- For example, in the case integrated geometric Brownian motion, one has $e^{B_{T_a}-\frac{1}{2}T_{a}}$ be equal in law to squared Bessel. Even possible to get Laplace transform for the inverse $T_{a}$.
- Another hope is to use Malliavin calculus to study that shifted process. One promising route is ["Hitting times for Gaussian processes"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606086.pdf) where they study $e^{X_{\tau_a}-R(\tau_{a})}$ for $X_{\tau_{a}}=a$, but some of the techniques can be modified to study $e^{X_{T_{a}}}$ instead. That work can be generalized to hitting times of additive functionals $\mu(x)=\int e^U$ i.e. $\mu(T_a)=a$. This is because instead of taking Malliavin derivative of the supremum at lemma 3.2, we can take that of $\mu(x)$.
- A beautiful result would be to bound by the unshifted moment
  $$E[\mu(T_{a},T_{a}+t)^{q}]\leq c E[\mu(0,t)^{q}],$$

for some uniform bound $c=c_{q}$. Usually such proofs go by Gaussian-interpolation but here $X_{T_a}$ is most likely not a Gaussian anymore. So one hope is to use the generalization of interpolation in Malliavin calculus ["Comparison inequalities on Wiener space"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2430). The issue here is that one seems to necesarily need Malliavin differentiability of $X_{T_a}$, which is not for similar reasons as here [possible](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377498/malliavin-derivative-of-stopped-brownian-motion/421474#421474).

Answer (score 1):

For any one interested in this type of shifted measure for fields with short-range correlation, we made some progress here in the article ["Inverse of the Gaussian multiplicative chaos: Moments"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.00360).

Basically, start with decomposing the variable $T_{a}$ and take supremum

$$E[\mu(T_{a},T_{a}+t)]\leq \sum_{k}E[\sup_{T\in I_{k}}\mu(T,T+t)\chi\{T_{a}\in I_{k}\}]$$

for some partition intervals $I_{k}=[a_{k},a_{k+1}]$. Next one either uses Holder inequality (or FKG inequality) to separate the two factors or a kind of strong-Markov decoupling that is true for fields with short-range correlation.

The factor $E[\sup_{T\in I_{k}}\mu(T,T+t)]$ can be studied using a chaining argument to reduce the supremum to maximum over finitely many intervals.

The factor $T_{a}\in I_{k}$ can be studied using single point estimates eg. for large $a_k$, we can use $\{T_{a}\geq a_{k+1}\}= \{a\geq \mu(a_{k+1}))\}$ and negative moments of $\mu$.